# How to include the first character in a RegEx match from the RegEx pattern?

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

> This is a test ::a. MODE 3 within 7 hours,
>
> ::b. MODE 4 within 13 hours, and
>
> ::c. MODE 5 within 37 hours
>
> :: My Test

And the following RegEx pattern:

```
(?<=^::[A-z ])(.*?)(?=$)
```

Testing on here: https://regex101.com/r/w1f0Dn/1

It identifies the results that I need correctly (not the first line as it should). However, I'm trying to include the first character as part of the match for the results.

Example:
the `::b. MODE` line finds the line, but it's not including the b as part of the match. I need the final match to be `b. MODE 4 within 13 hours, and` vs `.MODE 4 within 13 hours, and` Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not use `^::([A-Za-z ].*)` ?

Comment: That will include the `::` in the match

Comment: @JRiggles: Capture group in `^::([A-Za-z ].*)`

Comment: @anubhava Glazed over that, you're right!

Comment: If this is for PCRE you can also try [`^::\s*\K\b.+`](https://regex101.com/r/AT3gtC/1) which resets after the optional white-space letting your match start at word boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `[A-Za-z ]` group out of the lookbehind and into the 1st capture group: `(?<=^::)([A-Za-z ].*)`

Comment: Note that `A-z` is not the same as `A-Za-z` and if you want to match the rest of the line, this `.*?` does not have to be non greedy. You can omit the `(?=$)` as you are matching the rest of the line

Comment: True! I was just using the same char classing as OP

Comment: `(?=$)` can be removed because `.*` will match till end anyway

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too - gone!

Comment: As you are using a lookbehind, you can also omit the capture group :-)  `(?<=^::)[A-Za-z ].*`

Comment: @Thefourthbird True - I'm used to Python's `re.findall` which tends to behave more predictably with capture groups :]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `(?:^::\s*)(.*$)` is enough. No need to use any *look behind*.

Comment: I think you can get away without `\s*` in the non-capturing group -> `(?:^::)(.*$)`

Comment: You can omit the leading non capture group `(?:` as in this context it has no purpose